# selenium c# webdriver click on the select element from the list

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
 IList<IWebElement> tabButtons = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".atui-ui-button"));
 tabButtons.click();
```

What should I specify for it to click on second element from the list?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `lists of same elements` and would like to click on the second element you can use the `index`

```
IList<IWebElement> tabButtons = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".atui-ui-button"));
tabButtons[1].click();
```

It returns zero based list so first element is `tabButtons[0]` ,second is `tabButtons[1]` and so on..